# How to keep a flat file on HDFS in sync with a large database table?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

What's the best way of keeping a flat file on HDFS in sync with a large database table which may have row updates?

Tools such as sqoop seem like they'd be useful as they allow incremental extracts of new rows from tables, however I can't see an easy way of handling row updates.

What techniques can we use to handle row updates in an efficent manner? Dumping entire tables nightly is something we'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple suggestions:

- Use DBInputFormat to make the database the input to your jobs, instead of having an intermediate file that you have to worry about synchronizing.  If MySQL becomes a bottleneck, you can use some distributed/NoSQL database.
- If you still want to use flat files, each night you can only dump the rows that changed in MySQL, along with a timestamp.  Write a Hadoop job that outputs only the most recent version of each unique row.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer having an updated_at field in mysql table to only get the changed data every night. After that I do a simple map reduce to apply changes on (merge with) old state.